# Fitch Format Proofs - any resources around?

Tags: computer-science, first-order-logic, fitch-proofs

I am currently studying Fitch Format first order logic proofs. My lecturer follows closely [Language, Proof and Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157586374X) by Jon Barwise.

I am trying to do some proofs but I am having some trouble getting to understand how to do these proofs. As I have already read what Language Proof and Logic has to offer, I'd like to know if there are any other books or resources around that use the Fitch format for their formal proofs.

Plus, having solved exercises would be of great(!) help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly confident that LPL's exact Fitch format is unique to LPL. The general [Fitch-style proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch-style_calculus) concept comes from Fitch himself though it is probably not much of a help for you.

Here are [answers to selected exercises](http://web.archive.org/web/20101224183735/http://ggww.stanford.edu/NGUS/lpl/hints), though I think your best bet is to ask your instructor specific questions or work with a group of classmates.

Comment: That's good to know. I thought it was a general format for doing first order logic proofs. No wonder I was having trouble finding references to it in other FOL books. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Klement's proof checker that goes with the *forallx* textbook on logic are available online. Regarding the request:

> I'd like to know if there are any other books or resources around that use the Fitch format for their formal proofs.

With these two resources one should be able to learn truth functional and first order logic using a Fitch-style system of natural deduction. They would also provide a supplement to whatever text one is currently using.

---

Reference

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/